# Angular 5: how to listen for the selected option from component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

In angular I have a select element, in which I'm listing a list of objects like below:

```
<select class="m-1" (change)="valueChanged($event.target.value)">
   <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
      {{item.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

and this is the corresponding component code:

```
valueChanged(value: Item) {
    console.log('Selection Changed: ' + value.name);
}
```

but very surprisingly it logs as undefined, while if logging only `value` it prints `Selection Changed: "[object Object]"`

How can I get the current selected object in the selection handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using two-way binding with `[(ngModel)]`. You can monitor selection changes with `(ngModelChange)`. In order to use objects as select options, the values should be set with `[ngValue]`.

**HTML:**

```
<select class="m-1" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="valueChanged($event)">
   <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">
      {{item.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

**Code:**

```
selectedItem: Item;

valueChanged(value: Item) {
    console.log('Selection Changed', value);
}
```

---

**Using `(ngModelChange)` without data binding**

Event binding with `(ngModelChange)` can also be used without two-way data binding, but the `ngModel` directive must be applied to the element in order for that to work:

```
<select class="m-1" ngModel (ngModelChange)="valueChanged($event)">
   <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">
      {{item.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `$event` object completely in the `(change)` function and get the value from the corresponding method.

```
valueChanged(value: any) {
        console.log('Selection Changed: ' + value);
}
```